# Allow small edits

Tags: support, editing

For the upcoming MathJax/mhchem update, I'd like to make sure that old chemistry.SE posts do not break. I downloaded 12,000 unique usages of `\ce` and I have been using them as test cases.

Some of the posts use `\ce` in an ... 'exotic' way and I'd like to fix those, so that the update does not break them. Sometimes it is just a space missing.

However, I get the error message

> Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?

Is there a way to go around this restriction? Can an administrator give me rights for smaller edits?

Comment: Take a look at http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/3044/hidden-points-of-editing-you-probably-didnt-know; there are usually many other things in the post that can be improved. e.g. smileys, taglines, salutations etc.

Comment: In my opinion, if `\ce{...}` is used in an exotic way, it is the fault of the exotic users if it breaks — but mind I didn’t check what the actual exotic usages are; if they are chemical then they should probably stay.

Comment: Could you provide an example for the exciting usage? Maybe the use in such a case should be completely abandoned and substituted with a longer expression. For example, if it is used as `\ce{sp^3}` then it should be completely replaced by `\mathrm{sp^3}` and that should count as six characters.

Comment: @IͶΔ That is very true, but mhchem is also doing us a tremendous favor at the expense of their own time.

Comment: I think if links were posted, the community could edit them in short order.

Comment: @Jon I agree, and an idea just hit me. What if mhchem posted the questions he wants to edit but can't in chat? I et al. will be more than happy to help. :)

Comment: I downloaded 12000 usages of `\ce` from chemistry.SE. (Thanks for the export functionality, this helped me a lot!) There is quite some misuse (= not intended use). Like `\ce{25^0 C}` (quite some, you definitely need a number/unit macro) or `\ce{Hg/mercury(I) nitrate~~ (0.005M)//mercury(I) nitrate~~ (0.05M) /Hg}`. Some people used braces to change the parsing (and I would like to have that different) or added white space in strange ways. Most of these still render readable. Ther are only a few left that need a change. (Although I have way to go to finish inspecting the 12000).

Comment: One thing that I would love to change: I would like to enforce spaces around reaction arrows, because readable input is a major goal of mhchem. However, I estimate 500 `\ce`s here that would need a modification (out of the 12000). This means, I'd rather change my parser (and allow future space-less uses) than touching 400 posts.

Comment: @IͶΔ Chat would be fine, too.

Comment: Was I the only one using the `\cf` function instead of the `\ce` function?  I thought `\cf` was a lighter-weight alternative for formulae when you didn't need the full equation-like capabilities from `ce`.  I now have over 45 suggested edits to my old answers that replace all `\cf` usages with `\ce`....I'll definitely avoid using `\cf` from now on and as I guess a side benefit, all my old answers are showing up on the main page and getting more upvotes?  I guess I'll take it...:-\

Comment: @CurtF. I did not look at who used the `\cf`. Yes, it *was* the lightweight alternative in earlier LaTeX versions of mhchem. However, I deprecated it in recent versions, because using `\ce` just produces the same results. For MathJax, `\cf` is an alias for `\ce`. And if only a few people used it, I'd rather deprecate it in future versions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, unfortunately there isn't a way to get around this for users without the editing privilege (2000 rep).  People have proposed this as a feature on Meta.StackExchange numerous times, but it's thought that people would use it to "game" edits (not on our site in particular, but on a higher volume site like Stack Overflow, this is a problem).

So, there are a couple of things we can do.  We can either put some links to particular posts in here and someone with the editing privilege can take care of them and/or look for any minor cosmetic things that can be changed.  You will get the +2 rep bonus for the latter.

All that being said, on behalf of all of us, **thank you** and your team for all of your efforts to improve what is already an amazingly useful library!

Comment: I second that. And thanks again, it really helps this site a lot.